# How do I evenly wrap a mesh around a sphere

Tags: mesh

Ive tried using shrink wrap and it starts to do what I want but I cant get it to wrap around the whole thing. Only half of it.

[image]

Ive also tried using curves but I cant get it to evenly wrap into a sphere so that each point of the star is touching. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It might be easier just to texture a sphere, then unfold it. Save the spherical state of the object as a shape key, then create a new shape key where it's flat (or however you want it), then blend between the two.

Answer (score 3):

You don't tell a lot about why, for example, you begin with a flat shape, is it necessary? Anyway, I guess there are several ways to get the final shape. Here I tried *Cast* and *Array* modifiers.

If you need to start with a flat shape, you could do it with the **CAST** modifier:

- Create your star mesh.

[image]

- In *Object* mode, create a circle a bit above the star, made of some concentric edges loops, keep only the edges. Choose top orthographic view, select the circle, then the star, go in *Edit* mode and in the bottom menu bar choose *Mesh* > *Knife Project*, it's going to print the circle edges on the star geometry.

[image]

- Now your star has enough geometry for a nice deformation (here it's not optimal but you can rearrange it).

[image]

- Create an empty at the same point as the star origin. Give your star a *Cast* modifier with the empty as *Control Object*.

[image]

- Rise the empty a bit, play with the *Cast Factor*, the star is going to deform and shape as a sphere!!!!!!

[image]

- Keep a copy of your star + empty objects, apply the Cast modifier, to make your shape even more spherical you can shrinkwrap it.

[image]

You could do it with the **ARRAY** modifier:

- Create a UV Sphere. Keep only a segment.

[image]

- Create an empty at the sphere's origin point. Give your object an *Array* modifier / *Object Offset* mode, with the empty as *Object*.

[image]

- Choose the right array count, rotate the empty on the Z axis so that it recreate a complete sphere. Go in Edit mode to edit your segment.

[image]

- Edit your mesh until you get the result you want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can also do it from a diamond shape using an array modifier, a subdivision and a cast:

[image]

The only part to adjust is the diamond diagonal so that the array can merge successive parts and first/last, depending on the star branches wanted amount.

The array uses a rotated empty so that its occurrences append circularly.

Subdivision is set to 'simple': we only want here the cast to have enough geometry to bend the figure.

[image]

**Same principle using shape keys**

[image]

[image]